# 12.04 LTS Installs or runs from install CD using my 2nd monitor but won't run or show when installed

Tags: installation, multiple-monitors

When using the install CD in "try this mode" or during install my 2nd monitor shows up and works fine... It shows HP 20" monitor connected to the correct video controller.

I installed with the laptop screen shut even... doing everything via the 2nd monitor.

Once the install was completed 12.04 will no longer recognize the 2nd moitor and will not show that one is connected at all.  I've installed 2 or 3 times now and the same results.

How can I get my install to recognize that I have a 2nd monitor attached and that I want to use it.

HP Compaq 8510w Workstation NVIDIA Driver.  HP2035 20" monitor connected via a docking station (but it doesn't matter if it's connected to the docking station or the direct VGA port as I've tried both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This maybe a NVIDIA driver problem. I think it's not loaded during live mode, but gets installed and automatically loaded on hard install. 
Try disabling the NVIDIA driver from the "Additional drivers" in the [system configuration](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia).

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had tried that but diabling both versions of the NVidia driver helped solve the issue.